# How could I figure out this file's character encoding?

Tags: character-encoding

I have a data file that when I view it with vim, nano, or cat, will not be displayed properly and depending on the viewer, will be in different encodings. Here's an example line viewed by the TextEdit app on OSX:

```
….80RMî‘“q∂€r€mqpÄçÊ€~7€m∆
```

Here's with nano:

```
CҴPSRдϴ5^Cδ^T�-�ڴ^S�۴m�۴m�۴m�۴mT�-�ڴM�:��۴-��-�״^[m���۴]m�۶۶m�Ǫ�\�m�rN^RՅ
```

(I can't tell if they're the same line because they all have different lengths)

How could I decode it so it's readable?

Comment: Please explain 'displayed properly'.  The ability to be streamed as human-understandable text is not an inherent property of files.  Files are a container of binary data in sets of 8 bits.  That is all.

Comment: Also, try the `file` command.  It will tell you some stuff about the file.

Comment: Youre using OSX. So you can use `file -i yourfile.txt` and it will display the charset for you. If you want it to be readable try changing charset to UTF-8

Comment: @MartinJames "displayed properly" as in I have a general idea of what the file should look like if it were in a human readable format.

Comment: @TrippKinetics if I run file fileName, it just says fileName: data

Comment: Then it isn't a text file.  Not meant to be man-readable.

Comment: @ShreyasChavan I ran the command and it only says yourfile.txt: regular file. I actually have tried changing it to UTF-8 and UTF-16 and neither did anything.

Comment: @TrippKinetics That's why I'm confused, because I have a human readable version of the same data type (not the same file) hence why I have a good idea of what it should look like.

Comment: Define "data type".  The file extension doesn't really indicate the data type.